# Facing error when trying to open a new tab in selenium with --Headless=new enabled

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

```
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.addArguments("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.addArguments("--window-size=1920x1080");
options.addArguments("--headless=new");
options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9220");
```

Getting this error:

**unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Failed to open new tab - no browser is open"}**

i am expecting to open a new tab in headless mode in chrome